# Window won't maximize when "set_resizable" is false once (GTK3)

Tags: c, gtk3

When I create a new window and use the function `gtk_window_set_resizable` to false, `gtk_window_maximize` won't maximize the window anymore, even when I set `gtk_window_set_resizable` to true again. It does trigger a `"size-allocate"` event. How can I maximize the window properly?

Example:

```
// Create function
GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(win), false);
gtk_widget_show_all(win);

// Maximize function
gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(win), true);
gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW(win)); // This doesn't maximize the window
```

I'm running this on Debian Testing with XFCE 4 and GTK+3.18.

Comment: It's just a guess but maybe you can't change window's settings once you have showed it?

Comment: @wowofbob the maximize decoration does show up again when I call `gtk_window_set_resizable(.., true)`. I can also press it and then it maximizes properly, but `gtk_window_maximize` won't work.

Comment: Does it work if you call     gtk_widget_hide (GTK_WIDGET (win)); before set_resizable and gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (win)); after window_maximize ? If so, it is either a bug in Gtk or your window manager (report bug if so)

Comment: @StianSkjelstad this does maximize the window properly. I will file a bug report, thank you!